# Java iterate over a list and filter

Tags: java, spring

I have this entity:

```
public class StatementLinesEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long statementLinesId;
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateOperation;
private String operationNature;
private BigDecimal amount;
private String debitAmount;
```

I want iterate over this list `StatementLinesEntity` under 2 conditions.

- First: filter `debitAmount` which has to be equal to letter `C`  `(debitAmount == C)`
- Second: `operationNature` could be one of these 3 words (paymnt, check, cach)

After this filtering, I want to save this filtered list to database

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. I presume your question is, how can you do this? Well, what have you tried? There are countless examples of [filtering lists](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+filter+list) on StackOverflow. By the way, the spelling of `amount`, `payment`, and `cash` are all incorrect.

Comment: I tired this and didn't work: `List<LigneReleveEntity> ligneReleveEntities = ligneReleveRepository.findAll();
        ligneReleveEntities.stream().filter(cdebit -> ((Map)cdebit).get("creditDebit").equals("C")).toArray();`

Comment: That should go in your question, and you should explain what "didn't work" means. Did it not compile, did it throw an exception (which?), did you get the wrong results? You are casting the entity to a `Map` (and using a raw type), which doesn't make any sense. The entity does not implement the `Map` interface.

Comment: I'm trying to make a service that shouldn't be exposed means that I'll be using a workflow that takes care of that service, now this service is responsible for this question gets data from database and iterate over this list and then filter every line that has `C` finally gather this filtred list to save it to DB. so this process will be done automatically by a workflow. The thing is that I don't have much experience on arrays and maps,filters I just want to filter list and save filtred list to db

Comment: None of that answered anything. Why are you casting your entity to a map when your entity is not a map?

Comment: Pardon me Im not much experienced on this but what should I do to iterate and filter to reach that, David I can tell that you have much experience I can share my repo and hint with a suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Well, I would think it would be something like `ligneReleveEntities.stream().filter(entity -> entity.getDebitAmmount().equals("C")).filter(entity -> isValidOperation(entity.getOperationNature())).collect(Collectors.toList())` with a helper method that checks for the three operations, but now you're casting to `Map` and doing `get("creditDebit")` even though there's no "creditDebit" in your Entity that you've shown in your question. So it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Edit your question and put your real code in it, with `creditDebit` and whatever the real field names are, or the Map, if there is one.

Comment: David Thanks alot I followed your suggestion and made little change it worked like charm but I have a question I searched on all websites and found nothing.now I have another entity that has a inheritance of type single_table (OpCreditEntity) and 3 entities inherite from it(PaymentEntity,CheckEntity,CachEntity) so based on that filtering which consist on C and (paymnt || check || cach). [I'll post another comment for explanation]

Comment: I want to save each one in a specific DTYPE. example: I have 2 StatementLines one line has C & Virement and another line has C and Check now I have to save eash operation(line) to it's specific DTYPE based on Check or Virement or Payment. I did alot of research but nothing, Thnaks David